# javascript замена строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, в фукнцию поступает строка, к примеру

`<p>word</p> 1234 <span>hello</span> <li>string<li>`

как можно из данной строки сделать

```
 ^word^ 1234 &hello& $string$
```

тоесть  эти 3 html тэга заменить на символы которые я привёл в пример, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```js
const repl = {
    p: `^`,
    span: `&`,
    li: `$`
}

let str = `<p>word</p> 1234 <span>hello</span> <li>string<li>`;

str = str.replace(/<[/]{0,1}(p|span|li)>/g, (match, p1) => {
    return repl[p1];
});

console.log(str);
```

Написал и отправил не протестировав, потом протестировал и работает. Ну надо же :)